# Method which return 0

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I created a method to store the result of the request SQLite in a table

```
public ArrayList <String> getProductName(double idcat) 
    {
        ArrayList <String> tab = new ArrayList <String>();
         try
            {
                Cursor c = null;
                c = database.rawQuery("SELECT " + COL_PRODUCT_NAME + " FROM "
                        + TABLE_PRODUCT + " WHERE " + COL_CATEGORY + "=  '" + idcat + "'", null);

                for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
                {
                    tab.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_PRODUCT_NAME)));
                    c.moveToNext();
                  }
                c.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                return tab;
        }
```

I want to get the number of elements in this table, so i put this :

```
ArrayList <String> tab = new ArrayList <String>();
 TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tab=db.getProductName(1);
                int n =tab.size();
                tv.setText("n=" +n);
```

But when i compile my application, n get 0 !!! 
i want to know if my method is correct or not

Comment: Do you have an open connction to the database at that time?

Comment: Change `e.printStackTrace();` to `throw new RuntimeException(e);` to know or read the logs.

Comment: Are you getting any exception while reading from the DB?

Comment: Yes, the connection is open !!

Comment: No, i didn't get any exception !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make this call first before starting the Cursor iteration:

```
c.moveToFirst()
```

It should be something like this

```
if(c.moveToFirst()){
 //Loop here
}
```

Comment: 07-19 18:20:55.697: E/AndroidRuntime(7369): java.lang.RuntimeException: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 7
what the logcat display